# How do I send a command with a message to echo on success to a bash function?

Tags: bash, echo, bash-function

I've written a function to check if a command executed successfully, and if not, throw an error.

```
assert_success () {
    "$1"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        echo "$2"
    fi
}
```

Say I have the following command to execute with the given error :

```
assert_success <command> <error_message>
```

So basically, something like the following :

```
assert_success $(mkdir blah) "This worked"
```

However, I get `a.sh: line 3: This worked: command not found`

How do I get the `echo` to work correctly here?

Comment: Read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this call:

```
assert_success $(mkdir blah) "This worked"`
```

you are **passing output of `mkdir` command**, not the `mkdir` command itself. And since output of `mkdir` is empty and it is **unquoted** `"This worked"` becomes `$1` inside your function and you get error: `This worked: command not found`

I suggest you have your function like this:

```
assert_success () {
   msg="$1"
   shift
   if $@; then
      echo "$msg"
   fi
}
```

and call this function as:

```
assert_success "This worked" mkdir blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the issues discussed in the link in my comment, there is no need for such a function. It's shorter to simply run your command, then use the `&&` operator to print the success message. Compare

```
mkdir blah && echo "This worked"
```

with either

```
assert_success "mkdir blah" "This worked"
```

or anubhava's solution

```
assert_success "This worked" mkdir blah
```